# How to print an array to a text file in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, file-io, vector

I have an array of vectors:

```
array = [0 0 0 0 0 0 1  
         0 1 1 1 0 1 0  
         1 1 1 1 0 0 0  
         .............  
         .............]
```

and I want to print it into a file as it is:

```
0000001  
0111010  
1111000
....
....
```

etc.

I have this but it does not seem to work:

```
myoutput = fopen('c:\\aitest_file.txt', 'wt');
fprintf(myoutput, '%f\n', VAA_final);

fclose(myoutput);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
dlmwrite('c:\aitest_file.txt', VAA_final, 'delimiter', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to transpose your output matrix and use the appropriate number of integer identifiers:

```
>> VAA_final = [0 0 0 0 0 0 1; 0 1 1 1 0 1 0; 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]

VAA_final =

     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     0     1     1     1     0     1     0
     1     1     1     1     0     0     0

>> myoutput = fopen('aitest_file.txt', 'wt');
>> fprintf(myoutput, '%u%u%u%u%u%u%u\n', VAA_final');
>> fclose(myoutput);
```

Comment: thx!!!
my matrix was created like this
VAA_final = [VAA_final; Vector1]
that makes it already transpose.

Comment: it seems that it does not work. my values are not printed in order :/

Comment: it works. sorry, i forgot to transpose the matrix. it seems it did not do it.